# Is there an informational page or other list of rules specifically for Puzzling.SE?

Tags: support

Maybe I'm just overlooking it, but I cannot find guidelines for this specific site anywhere.  All the links (e.g., *What kind of questions should I ask on Puzzling?*) go to the generic Stack Exchange template.

Is there a list of

- what makes a bad/good puzzle?
- what kinds of puzzles are specifically banned?
- Puzzling.SE specific guidelines/rules?
- specific formatting tips for Puzzling (such as the spoiler markup)?

I know this must be around; I've looked hard but can't find it!

Comment: I think this information is supposed to go on the [help center page](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which is currently generic. There was some discussion in [this meta post](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/27/lets-populate-our-help-section/28), but I don't think anything concrete came of it. Probably it's time to try again.

Comment: More recently (though still about a year ago), [I asked this question](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1312/what-should-our-help-center-say-about-on-topic-questions), which received no responses. Maybe we should reopen that discussion?